# perl editor/IDE similar to source insight for C

Tags: perl, ide

I have recently started working with Perl. Googling reveals a number of editors but I am unable to find an editor that will help me navigate a large body of Perl source code. One of the features that I am looking for is the ability of the IDE to integrate with different modules and allow me to jump from one to another. If possible, it will also help if one can see the which function calls what. 
I used source insight for C programming and it provides these very useful features. Am looking for similar features in perl.

Help appreciated

Comment: perl is so dynamic that it is hard to do this as well as for a more static language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just giving EPIC a chance.
http://www.epic-ide.org/

Its an Eclipse plugin utilizing a mighty IDE. The advantage I see in using EPIC over Padre is the fact that eclipse can do all sorts of languages and I don't have to get used to multiple different editors every time.

Another great aproach for Perl programming is using emacs. Yes ... its old but I had quite some joy while getting into Perl.

cu
Roman

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/)?  It is a Perl IDE developed by the Perl community.

Answer (score 0):

Komodo IDE, from Active State is also quite good. I haven't used any other Perl IDEs so cannot make comparisons. Most of the features that you are looking for I believe are available in Komodo.

On a side note: The feature that I most appreciated in Komodo was visual debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use [jEdit](http://jedit.org) for Perl programming.

- The [PerlSideKick](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?PerlSideKick) plugin, allows you to navigate huge Perl modules (mainly just a plugin for the [SideKick](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?SideKick) plugin).
- But there's not much to give you that easy Shift+click navigation you get from Eclipse. jEdit is 100% programmable through Beanshell macros (and JavaScript and Python and JRuby...). So, you can do some of this yourself. So there would be work involved.

  For example, it been close enough for me to create "Selection macros" that will allow certain actions on the package or name either highlighted or at the caret. For example, open up the module indicated by the package name.
- The [Navigator](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?Navigator) plugin will at least remember where you were last across files.
- You might be able to do cross-module navigation through one of the [tags plugins](http://plugins.jedit.org/list.php)

So this won't get you *all the way* you'd want to go, but it will get you some of the way, and for $0.

- It has the most configurable source highlighting this side of writing Emacs-LISP.
- It does FTP and remote editing cleaner than most editors I've used.
- You can build up a library of Beanshell (shorthand Java) scripts that really help you get what you want done.

Just remember that this recommendation comes with caveats. I have found EPIC quite sub-standard for my use.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. I will try it :)